# redirect numerous dynamic urls to home page via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to clean up a previously hacked WordPress site, and domain name reputation, the site has new hosting and is now on a different CMS system, but there are hundreds of spam links in Google I need to get rid of, they look like `example.com/votes.php?10054nzwzm75042pw205039`

Domain name, then `votes.php?****` etc.. Numbers letters all sorts.

So how do I redirect ANYTHING that starts with the domain name then `/votes.php?***`

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have multiple domains, you don't need to explicitly check the domain name.

To send a "410 Gone" for anything that contains `/votes.php` in the URL-path (and *any* query string), you can do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Serve a 410 Gone for any requests to "/votes.php"
RewriteRule ^votes\.php$ - [G]
```

A 410 is preferable to a "redirect" if you want to get these URLs removed from the search engines as quickly as possible.

To expedite the process of URL removal from Google then use [Google's Removal Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en) as well.

If you redirect these pages to the homepage then it will likely be seen as a soft-404 by Google and these URLs are likely to remain in the search results for a lot longer.